# Copy Date object without old data

Tags: javascript, node.js, deep-copy

I'm trying to write custom deep clone functionality and I have some problems with the Date object. for example`let now = {time: new Date()}` or `let now = {data: new Date().getDay()}`, and I want to copy it, I don't need to copy current time, I only need to copy new Date() constructor, or new Date().getDay() functionality, for example, if I will run the original object now, and after a few days I will run the copy object, I don't need the same result, I need the recently get new Date() function result.

Comment: The result of a function call carries no reference to the function that returned it. Perhaps you're looking to simply define a Class? or perhaps a schema for the object?

Comment: Not only type of class, if we look only case new Date(), I can define it [object Date], but problem is that i get a same result for new Date().getTime(), Date.now() and ect, I can't define with which method was called in originally function

Comment: You will need to post more details for concrete help, ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

You can only get at the object as it were if you scan the source

Here using DOM as an example

```js
const script = [...document.querySelectorAll("script")]
 .filter(scr => scr.innerText.match(/let\s+now/))
if (script.length) console.log(script[0].textContent.trim())
```

```html
<script>
let time = {data: new Date().getHours()}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(time)))
</script>
<script>
let now = {data: new Date().getDay()}
</script>
```